# How to get the type of Algolia search results?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, full-text-search, next.js, algolia

My `firestore` is connecting with the `algoliasearch`. Im using `typescript` with `nextjs`.

I try to get the results as follow

```
products = index.search(name).then(({hits}) => {
  return hits
})
```

Then I store the results in a state so I can pass them down as a props to another component.
However, I constantly getting an error about type `ObjectWithObjectID`. I have installed `@types/algoliasearch`, but I cant seem to find the props for `ObjectWithObjectID`. Any work around on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to manually type what my 'hit' looked like, for example:

```
type AlgoliaHits = {
  hits: AlgoliaHit[];
};

export type AlgoliaHit = {
  identifier: string;
  cpi_visibility: string;
  title: string;
  published: string;
};

const content: AlgoliaHits = await index.search(searchText, {
  hitsPerPage: HITS_PER_PAGE,
  facetFilters: ["cpi_visibility:published"].filter(Boolean)
});
```

Comment: Please don't do that. See drewbietron's answer below, which should be the accepted answer. This uses type inference which sometimes breaks between TS releases.

Answer (score 2):

Calling `.search` on an index allows to pass in a type as a generic.  This will assign the type of `hits` returned to be the same type that's given.

```
const content = await index.search<AlgoliaHit>(searchText, {
  hitsPerPage: HITS_PER_PAGE,
  facetFilters: ["cpi_visibility:published"].filter(Boolean)
});
```

This will also give `content` the type `SearchResponse<AlgoliaHit>` which will give you some nice autocomplete on the properties available on `content`;

```
content.hits.map(hit => 
  console.log(hit, "<- this has every property that you've defined in AlgoliaHit")
)
```

Comment: This is the correct way. Should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to import the types, you can use the below:

```
import { SearchResponse } from '@algolia/client-search';
```