# How to cast algolia search result to Type/Interface in typescript

Tags: algolia

I am using Algolia search with Typescript. The search result looks like:

```
{
  hits: [
    {
      author: 'Author 1',
      eventCategory: 'Major',
      book: 'My Book1',
      eventStarTime: 1683081900,
      eventID: 2323213,
      objectID: 'o-871278123',
      _highlightResult: [Object]
    },
    {
      author: 'Author 1',
      eventCategory: 'Major',
      book: 'My Book2',
      eventStarTime: 1683084000,
      eventID: 2344244,
      objectID: 'o-871278456',
      _highlightResult: [Object]
    }
  ],
  nbHits: 2,
  page: 0,
  nbPages: 1,
  hitsPerPage: 20,
  exhaustiveNbHits: true,
  exhaustiveTypo: true,
  exhaustive: { nbHits: true, typo: true },
  query: '',
  params: 'filters=isAuthor+%3D+1',
  processingTimeMS: 1,
  processingTimingsMS: { request: { queue: 4, roundTrip: 4 } },
  serverTimeMS: 4
}
```

How can I parse this object to a custom interface? I am only interested in the following fields:
author, eventCategory, book, eventStarTime, eventID, objectID

Ideally I want an array or list of my custom interface.

Can I do:

```
const searchResponse: SearchResponse = await index.search('', {
        filters: filters,
        attributesToRetrieve: ['author', 'eventCategory','book','eventStarTime','eventID'],
      });
const hits: Array<Hit<TObject>> = searchResponse.hits;
```

How do I cast to Array<Hit>? Are Hit and TObject importable?

Thanks

Comment: do you have an interface? something like `interface SearchResult { author: string; eventCategory: string; book: string; eventStarTime: number; eventID: number; objectID: string; }`. you can map the hits array and get a SearchResult array

Comment: Thanks @cmgchess. I am trying to do 
``` const searchResponse: SearchResponse = await index.search('', {
        filters: filters,
        attributesToRetrieve: ['author', 'eventCategory','book','eventStarTime','eventID'],
      });
const hits: Array<Hit<TObject>> = searchResponse.hits; 
```
How do I cast to Array<Hit<TObject>>? Are Hit and TObject importable?

Comment: The following question may help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62359944/how-to-get-the-type-of-algolia-search-results#answer-70269619